# Sci-fi short story: plants attracting spaceship and using them as a agents of pollination between two planets

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Science fiction - short story - of plants attracting spaceship and using them as a agents of pollination between two planets

Comment: Oof, that's a bit short. Any other memory you could [edit] in? For instance when did you read that? When would it have been published?

Comment: Hi, karthik! Welcome to Stack Exchange. See [our guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999) for some help improving this question.

Comment: *&^$&*(%&*%! I've read this story; just can't bring the title to mind.I want to say that it was an Asimov, but a quick look at his [short story bibliography on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov_short_stories_bibliography) doesn't ring any bells.

Comment: Short description.  To the point.  I recognized the story just from the **title** of the question.

Comment: This sounds like a story I know but cannot unfortunately remember the name.  In the story I am thinking off there is a spaceship, the crew finds something strange (another spaceship I think) and when they board it the crew begins to change.  Eventually it is revealed that technology using sapients (like humans) are basically the pollen that planets use to spread their form of life around the galaxy.  If that sounds like the story you want perhaps the additional details will help someone else identify it.

Answer (score 20):

[Each an Explorer](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58940) by Isaac Asimov. Also identified as the answer to [Mind Controlling Invasive Alien Plants](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144744/mind-controlling-invasive-alien-plants).

Two explorers, Allen Smith and Herman Chouns, suffer an unexpected failure of their hyperatomic motors as they approach a system with two planets. They land on one of the planets to make repairs and find primitive natives who give them sophisticated and valuable equipment called Gamow hyperspatial sighters. When asked where the sighters came from the natives indicate the other planet, so Chouns and Smith dash off there to find more.

The story is as you say in your question. The plants are intelligent and have telepathic powers. They made the explorers think the drive had failed when it hadn't, and they made the explorers believe they were seeing hyperspatial sighters when they weren't. The aim of the plants is to get the explorers to go to the other planet and carry pollen with them.

As Smith explains to Chouns when they leave:

> “But we were the agents that arranged for the mingling. We landed on one planet and were coated with pollen. Remember the blooms closing? That must have been just after they released their pollen; and that’s what was making us sneeze, too. Then we landed on the other planet and knocked the pollen off our clothes. A new hybrid strain win start up. We were just a pair of two-legged bees, Chouns, doing our duty by the flowers.”

There is a twist in the tale:

> The *primitive natives* were once a spacefaring race who the plants mentally enslaved to look after them. Chouns and Smith are unwittingly carrying the spores back to Earth where the plants will do the same to humans.

Comment: Thank you; this is exactly the story I couldn't think of.

Comment: @ruakh oops, yes, thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks a ton @JohnRennie and thank you all that was the story I was looking for

Comment: @karthik if this is the story please will you click on the little tick symbol to mark the question as accepted. Thanks :-)